# Error in BoxCoxTransform(Xs, i) : could not find function "ln"

Tags: r

I 'am trying to use ln function in R, but it seems there is a problem. I've got this message :

> "Error in BoxCoxTransform(Xs, i) : could not find function "ln"".

Any idea pease?

```
BoxCoxTransform = function(Xskewed, lambda){

if(lambda !=0){

Xnormalized = (Xskewed^lambda-1)/(lambda)

} else {

Xnormalized = ln(Xskewed)

}

return(Xnormalized)

}
```

Comment: use `log` ( if you need log with base exp)

Answer (score 1):

If by `ln()` you mean natural log? Then function `log` in base is the natural logarithm.

Comment: @Batanichek, you could have posted that comment as an answer if you wanted (and indeed arguably you should have). I think it's polite to acknowledge an answer that draws from a comment (but this answer could certainly have been written independently)